# can't start mongodb in pop os

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

show following error in terminal, already tried uninstall reinstall still not working.. even in mongodb compass GUI its not starting its show `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-05-31 14:39:04 IST; 1min>
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 9642 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exi>
   Main PID: 9642 (code=exited, status=2)

May 31 14:39:04 pop-os systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
May 31 14:39:04 pop-os mongod[9642]: Error parsing YAML config: duplicate key: >
May 31 14:39:04 pop-os mongod[9642]: try '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more info>
May 31 14:39:04 pop-os systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=ex>
May 31 14:39:04 pop-os systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-cod>
```

Comment: `Error parsing YAML config` <-  bad config file?

Comment: I haven't touched this file..